# Execute something only when some time has been elapsed

Tags: c#, events, time, timer, vote

This is kinda hard to explain for me but look:

I made a MMORPG server launcher wich has a start button, whe you click it a little window pops up and asks you to vote for the server and then you can click start again to launch the game(there is a 10 sec countdown before you can actually start the game)

The only thing is that the vote website only accepts a vote from an user each 12 hours(IP and cookie based) and after someone has voted once, it is kinda annoying to have that little window pop up and wait each time you want to start the game.

My idea is:
When someone clicks to open the vote window, his system's date and exact hour aer written into a file.

After that, each time you click start the launchers reads that date and time and calculates if 12 hours have been elapsed since you last voted, if yes, it will ask you again to vote and IF NOT, it will just skip that part and directly start the game.

I'm not very experienced and I don't know where to start and how to make this work, your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Here's my event if it can help.

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var voteForm = new VoteWindow();
        voteForm.Show();
        voteForm.BringToFront();
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
```

And here is my code for actually starting the game.

```
    private void btnStart2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string error1 = "Deleted because it was too long...";
        string title1 = "Deleted because it was too long...";

        if (File.Exists("engine.exe"))
        {
            Process.Start("engine.exe", "/load /config debug");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error1, title1, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: on an unrelated note, why are doing this:
voteForm.Show();
        voteForm.BringToFront();
        this.Enabled = false;
?? why not use ShowDialog() instead?

Comment: I am not using ShowDialog because I alrady tried and had some issues with it, the one I'm using right now perfectly does the same taks and BringToFront is to be sure its on top of the main form. Also Disable is to disable and freeze the main form while the vote one is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Properties.Settings`. You can create a new setting by going to your `Solution Explorer` then expand `Properties` and open up `Settings.Settings`. On this page you can create a new `System.DateTime` object. Then you would do something like this.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;

    if (ts.TotalHours > 12)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = DateTime.Now;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        var voteForm = new VoteWindow();
        voteForm.Show();
        voteForm.BringToFront();
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I customized it by adding else 
{} for the action that would occur if 12 hours havent elapsed(in my case start the game)